# merge two files by key if exists in the first file / bash script

Tags: file, bash, unix, join, merge

i have two files with columns sorted by the value of the first column, and i want to merge them only if the value of the second exists in the first one.

The first file is like this

```
man01 xxx yyy zzz
man02 xxx yyy zzz
man03 xxx yyy zzz
man04 xxx yyy zzz
```

The second file

```
man01 sss
man08 sss
```

And the desired output is

```
man01 xxx yyy zzz sss
man02 xxx yyy zzz
man03 xxx yyy zzz
man04 xxx yyy zzz
```

I tried join but requires values of second file exist in the first one :/

Comment: Do you have empty line between records?

Comment: Looks like a good job for Perl, doesn't it?  (If anyone can think of a reasonable way to solve this using basic tools, I'll be impressed!)

Comment: I dont have much time, but `comm` and `paste` can prove handy, read their `man` pages

Comment: no wait, that's a job for `join` :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Join can do this, have you considered the `-a` option ? It will produce a line for each unpairable file line in a.txt and b.txt.

```
join -a1 a.txt b.txt

man01 xxx yyy zzz sss
man02 xxx yyy zzz
man03 xxx yyy zzz
man04 xxx yyy zzz
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it ain't a beauty of elegant command-line usage, but what about this?

```
perl -we 'open F1, "<file1.txt"; open F2, "<file2.txt"; my %f2 = map {/(\S+)/ ? ($1=>$_) : ()} <F2>; while (<F1>) { chomp; print; if (/(\S+)/ && exists $f2{$1}) { $f2{$1} =~ /\S+\s+(.*)/ and print " $1"; } print "\n"; }'
```

*Update:*  While I was working on the above, it seems as though @bunting and @c00kiemon5ter came up with a much more elegant answer.  Excellent!